# Re-running javascript code with out having to write it again

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding Javascript in Node.js, I have this function.

```
  function addaccountfunc(usrnew, passnew) {
  console.log(" Forgotten passwords/usernames can NOT be reset!")
  if (usrnew === usr ){
  console.log("Sorry, that username is taken, would you like to chose another?")   

    }
     var usrnew = prompt("Chose a username: ")

     if (passnew != password){
     var passnew = prompt("Chose a password:")
    }


    }
```

The problem is I would like to keep re running the usrnew prompt, until a username is entered that does not equal something already in the database, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a while loop:

```
var usrnew = prompt("Choose a username: ")
while(usrnew === usr) {
    console.log("Sorry, that username is taken, would you like to choose another?")   
    var usrnew = prompt("Choose a username: ")
}
```

Comment: you're welcome! I would appreciate if you just accept this answer and upvote please

Comment: I had to wait 9 mins. Will do now though.

Comment: Did I do something wrong? that was a perfect answer.